# jQuery: infinite fadeOut $ fadeIn effect?

Tags: jquery

I want to animate the label using `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` effect. But that code freezes the browser. How to fix that ?

```
function animateLabels() {
   $('label.orange-font').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).fadeIn(1000,function(){ animateLabels(); }});
}
```

Comment: missing `)` should be: `animateLabels() });});}` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCqD6/)

Comment: Yes, works nicely :) http://jsfiddle.net/8PULr/1/

Comment: Did we solve your problem @Tony? :)

Answer (score 4):

### Update ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/23RvM/1/))

Okay, I got a bit bored, so made a plugin for jQuery, lol. It's essentially the `pulsate` effect, but with a few additional options.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.pulsate = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            fadeIn: 1000,
            fadeInDelay: 150,
            fadeOut: 1000,
            fadeOutDelay: 150            
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        function fadeOutIn(element) {
            $(element || this).delay(settings.fadeOutDelay)
                .fadeOut(settings.fadeOut)
                .delay(settings.fadeInDelay)
                .fadeIn(settings.fadeIn, fadeOutIn);
        }           

        return this.each(function() {
           fadeOutIn(this); 
        });
    };    
})(jQuery);
```

Then pulsate like so:

```
$('label.orange-font').pulsate();

// or with options
$('label.orange-font').pulsate({
    fadeIn: 500,
    fadeOut: 2000
});
```

### Original ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/23RvM/))

Alternatively, you could try using the `delay` method, like so

```
function pulsate(element) {
    $(element || this).delay(150).fadeOut(1000).delay(150).fadeIn(1000, pulsate); 
}
```

Then pulsate like so:

```
pulsate($('label.orange-font'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method too:

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/23RvM/7/)

```
function myRepeat() {
    $('div').delay(150).fadeOut(1000).delay(150).fadeIn(1000); 
}
setInterval(myRepeat,500);
```