# asp.net jquery radiobuttonlist in updatepanel fadeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fadeout

I updated my post in order to show you the html. thanks by the way

I would like to click the submit button which will make the `Radiobuttonlist` fade out. I tried many things but couldn't do it.

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel1">

                                                    <span>Looking at the image attached, what is the most likely diagnosis?</span>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_poll" value="Item 1" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_0">Item 1</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_poll" value="Item 2" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_1">Item 2</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_poll" value="Item 3" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_2">Item 3</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_poll" value="Item 4" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbl_poll_3">Item 4</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_poll_submit" value="Button" onclick="fadePoll();" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_poll_submit" />
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the HTML code this generates.

Comment: I posted this source code to be more specific. I am sorry but I couldnt see the point of posting the html.I am very new to this stuff, so please dont get me wrong. I am not trying to be rude

Comment: No problem - but traversing the DOM with jQuery is based on the HTML generated by this code. The main problem we have is that the `id` attributes in your code are not guaranteed to match those in the final HTML. Also, we need to see how the `RadioButtonList` HTML is structured - is there a parent element, is it a `div`, `ul` etc?

Comment: I used $('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %>').fadeOut() and it works. it fades out but It comes back again... any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes and now i can see its fadeout on btn_poll_submit click

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_poll" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <asp:Button ID="btn_poll_submit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("input[id$=btn_poll_submit]").click(function (e) {    
             $("table[id$='rbl_poll']").fadeOut();
             e.preventDefault();
         });
     });         
</script>
```

Comment: this works though     $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=btn_poll_submit.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                    $('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %>').fadeOut();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });

Comment: I have missed a $ and now my code should work as it is, But good to hear its working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$("*[name$='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbl_poll'").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: fade out your radio button

Comment: thank you very much for your help. But I found a working solution and it is    $('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %>').fadeOut(2000); but it fades out 2 seconds and comes back. how can i disable forever

Comment: I'am happy to help you Arif, you can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777997/jquery-infinite-fadeout-fadein-effect

Comment: Still, I couldnt get it done. It fades out properly but I comes back again.