# JQuery Infinite Pulse Function with visibility:hidden instead of display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-animate

I have this infinite pulsate function

```
function pulsate(element) {
    $(element || this).delay(150).fadeOut(1000).delay(150).fadeIn(1000, pulsate); 
}
```

which taken from
[jQuery: infinite fadeOut $ fadeIn effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777997/jquery-infinite-fadeout-fadein-effect)

and I want to make pulse effect with `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`

I've read this thread
[jQuery fadeOut without display none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549389/jquery-fadeout-without-display-none)
But still confusing. 
How do I implement this `visibility:hidden` method to the infinite pulsate function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pulsate(element) {
    $(element || this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, pulsate);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QWujL/

Comment: Exactly as I want. Thanks @chrx :)

Comment: Just a note, having a recursive function like this will raise the maximum stack size, and killing or stopping animation if you need to will be terribly slow, instead of using recursive animation, use recursive timeouts, because they can be cleared easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fadeTo with the opacity of 0.01 instead of fadeOut, I believe the element will remain, but it will be invisible to the naked eye.

That way you don't have to faff about with visibility hidden at all.